# MagicalRecord shouldImport creates empty entity when returning NO

Tags: ios, objective-c, magicalrecord

I have a Publication object which has "n" Comment objects. I'm using

```
[publication MR_importValuesForKeysWithObject:dictionary];
```

for importing the publication and the comments objects from a JSON fetched from a server parsed into a NSDictionary.

In my Comment.m file I'm implementing shouldImport so a Comment object can only be created once if they have the same server id.

```
- (BOOL)shouldImport:(id)data {
    Comment *comment = [Comment MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"server_id" withValue:data[@"server_id"] inContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]];
    if (!comment) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

But for some reason the Comment objects gets created anyways, but with empty data. For example. I have a Comment with server_id "1", and I fetch from the server this object 3 more times, then shouldImport gets called this 3 times, returns NO but creates 3 empty objects related to the proper Publication object.

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find any way to prevent the entity from being created, so what I ended up doing was just to delete the entity if it shouldn't be imported like this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldImport:(id)data {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext];
    Comment *comment = [Comment MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"api_id" withValue:data[@"id_comentario"] inContext:context];
    if (!comment) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        [self MR_deleteInContext:context];
        return NO;
    }
}
```